# How to fix - Cannot load driver class: com.vertica.jdbc.Driver

Tags: spring-boot, vertica

I am a newbie at Java SpringBoot and am trying to create a simple application which returns result from a select query in Vertica database

In my `application.properties` file I have created a database connection like this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:vertica://<URL>:<Port>/<DB>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.vertica.jdbc.Driver
```

And I have a `RestController` defined like this -

```
package com.example.demo3;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class QueryExecutor {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List ExecuteQuery () {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from schema.mytable");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

And these are the dependencies in my `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

But when I compile my project I get below error -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.vertica.jdbc.Driver
```

I have download and placed the vertica driver `vertica-jdbc-9.2.1-0.jar` under `C:\Users\<windowsuser>\Sun\Java` and I have this jar file path in `Path` variable in `User variables` and `Path` variable in `System variables` in `System Properties`. Also in `intelliJ Idea IDE` in `application.properties` file the `com.vertica.jdbc.Driver` value is in red and gives error `Cannot resolve class or package vertica`.

How can I successfully register the vertica database driver in my windows 10 machine?

Comment: I don't think that the PATH variable is enough. Have you set it in %CLASSPATH%, too?

Comment: @user979189 Did you manage to solve it. I am facing the same issue, done all the same things but getting a different error

Answer (score 2):

I have not used this database driver, but I guess this is because there is no import the driver correctly.

You can try to add this to the `pom.xml`, and reimport.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vertica/vertica-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vertica</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertica-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added this to my pom.xml, but it it give me error - Cannot resolve com.vertica:vertica-jdbc:unknown in Sync Window and this dependency values are in red font, which means Maven is not able to resolve these dependency. I also downloaded version 9.1.1 of this driver since that is the highest Maven provides at this point, but no luck. Anything else I may be missing or doing wrong?

Comment: According to my shallow experience, the package was not successfully imported by maven. you can try to import this package manually. But I am worried that it will mislead you.